# Как изменить PHP переменную с помощью Ajax jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть файл *api_for_mobile.php*, который в приложение передает переменную `$SALE = false;` (означает что цены для акции скрыты), когда мы редактируем ее на `true`, то цены в приложении меняются, к чему все это, мне не тяжело зайти и поменять с `false` на `true`, но хочется сделать так, чтобы человек заходил на отдельную страницу и нажав кнопку менял с `false` на `true` и обратно.

Я просто не особо силен в AJAX, могу дать код для понимания.

```
if ($getVar == "pricing") { // цены
    $SALE = false;
    $endDate = "16.10.2018";
    $array_pricing = array(
        "com.b2c.all.programs.1.month"              => array( "price" => "$2", "discount" => "$1.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.3.month"              => array( "price" => "$5", "discount" => "$3.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.6.month"              => array( "price" => "$9", "discount" => "$6.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.12.month"             => array( "price" => "$12", "discount" => "$8.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.1.month"               => array( "price" => "$2", "discount" => "$1.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.3.month"               => array( "price" => "$5", "discount" => "$3.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.6.month"               => array( "price" => "$9", "discount" => "$6.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.12.month"              => array( "price" => "$12", "discount" => "$8.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.1.month"  => array( "price" => "$3", "discount" => "$1.99" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.3.month"  => array( "price" => "$7", "discount" => "$4.99" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.6.month"  => array( "price" => "$12", "discount" => "$8.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.12.month" => array( "price" => "$20", "discount" => "$13.99" )
    );
    if ( !$SALE ) { //если акции нет, очищаем discount
        foreach ($array_pricing as &$price) {
            unset($price["discount"]);
        }
    } else {
        $array_pricing["endDate"] = $endDate;
    }
    echo json_encode( $array_pricing ); // вывод на страницу статуса
}
```

Comment: конечно давайте код, от чего нам отталкиваться то ? :)

Comment: @madfan41k     Добавил в описание код

Comment: Обычно, я присваивал переменную `$SALE` в js переменную, например внутри html `<script> var sale = '<?$SALE?>' </script>`
и тогда в `success` ajax запроса можно ей управлять

Comment: не очень понятно с вашего кода, как я понимаю вы передаете переменную $getVar, почему вам и не передать туда переменную $sale ?

Comment: @Павел Игоревич а можно пример?

Comment: @madfan41k     не особо секу как выполнить это(